# garbage value in while printing array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, new-operator

I am declaring the array dynamically using new. The array is formed of string length, which I am giving from the user. When I am providing a string of length between 7-11 the array is printing garbage value. Why is it happening?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<climits>
#include<vector>
#include<ctime>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string str;
    cin>>str;
    int i,j;
    int** arr = new int*[str.length()];
    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        arr[i] = new int[str.length()];

    for(i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        for(j=0;j<str.length();j++){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output for string "BBABCBCAB" is:

```
36397056 0 8 0 -1 0 1111573058 1094926915 0 
0 0 4 0 -1 0 1111573058 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Why is it happening ? And not for other any string with more than length 12?

Comment: "Prints garbage". Did you expect roses?

Answer (score 5):

You're default-initializing all your `int`s, which doesn't actually assign them a value. Reading from an indeterminate value is undefined behavior - sometimes you get 0s, sometimes you get some weird values. Undefined behavior is undefined.

If you want all 0s, you need to value-initialize the array:

```
arr[i] = new int[str.length()]();
//                            ^^
```

Or use something like [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) or [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) or [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n).

Comment: Thanks, I will use memset from now on.

Comment: No I am still getting error.
Whenever I am using cin>>str it is showing error.
http://ideone.com/kSIQkA

Comment: @Uchiha_itachi You're not getting an "error" - you're getting behavior that differs from what you want. Your problem is that you did not read the documentation for `memset`.

Comment: I get it. I should have done sizeof(arr[0])*10 there.